# Displaying 3D medical images using Java 3D

Tags: java-3d, dicom

I have medical image (.dcm file) with me. Working with Java 3D API in eclipse. I am unable to code to display 3D image. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question about reading the DICOM image or some problem using Java 3D?

Comment: Hello  whiskeyspider, I want to Read DICOM image and Display. In Java 3D, not getting any way to display DICOM 3D image. Is there other way to do so in Java?

Comment: There isn't anything built-in to read DICOM.  You may look around for a Java reader, but that will only get you the intensity data.  You would still need to convert it to 3D data yourself (for example using Marching Cubes).  It's a lot of work, frankly.

Answer (score 1):

There are many unknowns in your question.
First of all, if you have a 3D dataset, like CT or MRI this will consist of several DICOM files (series), not just one (however there are 3D DICOM objects consisting of just a single file, like RTDOSE).
Second of all, what kind of 3D visualization do you expect? A CT for instance can be visualized as a set of slices, or as a voxelized and sliced volume in three views (axial, coronal, and sagittal), or it can be tessellated to display a 3D surface, or ray-traced as in volumetric rendering.

For reading DICOMs in Java there are many open libraries (like http://eviewbox.sourceforge.net/), just pick the one you like the most.

You may also consider using Java wrapper for VTK (http://www.vtk.org), that will allow you reading DICOMs and visualize the data, but no Java3D involved in this case.

Comment: Yes Archie, I have 3D data set of CT, MRI. I want to code for all kind of visualization you have mentioned. Currently I am trying to do it using ImageJ (ij.jar). Am I on right track?

Comment: Never did it with ImageJ, but I suppose with VolumeJ (http://webscreen.ophth.uiowa.edu/bij/vr.htm), which is based on ImageJ, some volumetric rendering can be performed.

Comment: I did it using jogl. Much easier. Thank you all for support.